# IntelliJ IDEA - Key board right click doesn't work

Tags: intellij-idea, right-click

I am using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate v 13.1, and I am fond of using key board short cuts, rarely use mouse. I am relatively new to this IDE as earlier I always worked on eclipse.

My question is about performing right click operations by pressing the right click key on key board (usually found near the right side Ctrl key on external key boards). The problem is when I press this key, nothing happens but when I click the mouse right click and things just happen. This is applicable on editor, project explorer and I guess everywhere in the IDE.

Is there a switch I should turn on and it will work or any other way to get key board right click work in IDEA? Thanks very much for your responses.

Comment: Works for me in IntelliJ 14. Try the community edition to confirm that is is a problem with 13.

Comment: Thanks sm4, I will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes accidents just happen for good! This one falls in that category :)

Somehow IDEA was unable to load any of my projects, and I thought of deleting '.IntelliJIdea13' directory from my user directory. Initially I didn't change my keymap (shortcuts) to Eclipse and right click just works fine.

In any case the problem is there for IntelliJ to fix. They should allow right click from keyboard to work even when shortscuts are mapped to Eclipse style.

I tried to change the shortcuts to Eclipse and keyboard right click stopped working. When I change it to default, it starts working.

Comment: I simply copied the eclipse shortcuts and added a new shortcut for showing context menu which is exactly what I wanted. :)

Answer (score 20):

I know it is an old question, but it popped up as 1st result when I searched for my issue, and I figured it out with some of the context in Ketan@'s answer.

Fix:

- Go to File -> Settings -> Keymap
- Search for "Show Context Menu"
- Add a new keyboard shortcut. When prompted, press the "right click" (aka "context menu") key.

Comment: Oddly my right click context menu disappeared in IntelliJ 2020.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (I think when opening a recently created 2nd project that I had no problems with previously) and this answer led me to the solution to simply remap it. Right clicked worked everywhere else in the OS. Not sure how it got unmapped in IntelliJ. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I had recently disabled right click on the mouse from mac settings.. thanks to intellij and the section "show context menu" in preferences/keymap and "add mouse shortcut" for reminding me - the clue was the "click" response from intelliJ when I pressed the right click of the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

For me, It simply works after just **restart the IntelliJ IDE**

Answer (score 0):

If you was installed it with jetbrains toolbox you can't made it easily.

I made a script written in php but you could adapt it to other languages:

https://gist.github.com/MrFiregore/0ba76d74f070b07eda5a12f3f24ba054

```php
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);
    define("__ROOT__", realpath(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", __ROOT__ . "php-error.log");
    $script_dir = 'E:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\scripts';
    
    function getAllFiles ($dir, $fileType = ['bmp', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'])
    {
        if (!is_dir($dir)) {
            return false;
        }
        $files = [];
        readFiles($dir, $files, $fileType);
        // var_dump($files);
        return $files;
    }
    
    
    function readFiles ($dir, &$files, $fileType = ['bmp', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'])
    {
        $handle = opendir($dir);
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
                continue;
            
            $filePath = $dir == '.' ? $file : $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
            if (is_link($filePath)) {
                contiune;
            }
            else if (is_dir($filePath)) {
                readFiles($filePath, $files);
            }
            else {
                $pathinfo = pathinfo($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file);
                $file_ext = isset($pathinfo['extension']) ? $pathinfo['extension'] : null;
                
                if (!in_array($file_ext, $fileType)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (strpos($file, '_cropface') === false) {
                    $files[] = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    
    $listFiles  = getAllFiles(realpath($script_dir), ["cmd"]);
    d(realpath($script_dir));
    foreach ($listFiles as $file) {
        $f    = pathinfo($file);
        $path = $file;
        $name = $f["filename"];
        
        $contents = file_get_contents($path);
        $pattern  = '/start\\s""\\s\\W\\w+\\W\\s"([a-zA-Z]:\\\\[\\\\S|*\\\\S]?.*)"/';
        preg_match($pattern, $contents, $m);
        $program_path = $m[1];
        $skipped_path = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $program_path);
        preg_match('/apps\\\\([a-zA-Z]+)\\W?[a-zA-Z]?\\\\/', $program_path, $program_name);
        $program_name = $program_name[1];
        
        $reg_data = <<<EOL
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
; $program_name
; when you right click a folder while holding shift
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\\$program_name]
@="Abrir directorio con $program_name"
"Icon"="$skipped_path,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\\$program_name\command]
@="$skipped_path \"%V\""

; when you right click a folder
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\\$program_name]
@="Abrir directorio con $program_name"
"Icon"="$skipped_path,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\\$program_name\command]
@="$skipped_path \"%1\""

; when you right click a file
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\\$program_name]
@="Abrir fichero en $program_name"
"Icon"="$skipped_path,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\\$program_name\command]
@="$skipped_path \"%1\""

; when you right click a folder
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\\$program_name]
@="Abrir directorio con $program_name"
"Icon"="$skipped_path,0"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\\$program_name\command]
@="$skipped_path \"%1\""
EOL;
        $reg_file = __ROOT__ . $program_name . ".reg";
        error_log("creando $reg_file");
        file_put_contents($reg_file, $reg_data);
        exec("regedit.exe /S " . realpath($reg_file));
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29891892)